# References about spectral theory on Hyperbolic space

Tags: reference-request, sp.spectral-theory

Can anyone suggest me some  books or papers that include details about spectral theory on Hyperbolic spaces or related topics such as scattering theory on Hyperbolic spaces?

After some googling, I can only find papers by Jean-Philippe Anker and Vittoria Pierfelice about Schrodinger equations on Hyperbolic spaces, see e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3523. I hope to find some references that contain more basic theory on Hyperbolic space, such as the spectral theory of Laplacian on $\mathbb{H}^n$ . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scattering Theory for Automorphic Functions, by Lax and Phillips?

Comment: Iwaniec's spectral theory of automorphic forms is a well-known reference (although not using representation theoretical language). One might also consider the Gelbart-Jacquet article (which is a bit advanced). If one wants to really study automorphic representations, then Bump's book or Borel's are natural starting points.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~davidb/spths.pdf (Introduction to Spectral Theory on Hyperbolic Surfaces, by David Borthwick) and http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02830802 (The geometry and spectra of hyperbolic manifolds, by Peter D. Hislop) and references therein.

This reference http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157386901596 (Chaos on the pseudosphere, by N.L. Balazs and A. Voros) might be also useful, although it is written for physicists.